# Extract Halfspace representation of a ConvexHullMesh

Tags: computational-geometry

I have computed the convex hull of a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ using `ConvexHullMesh`. This describes a convex polytope $\mathcal{P}$. I was wondering if there is any easy way of getting a matrix $A$ and a vector $b$ such that the polytope is given by: $\mathcal{P} = \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^{n} \,|\, Ax \leq b  \}$.

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 6):

In M12 you can use [`LinearOptimization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearOptimization). An example [`ConvexHullMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh):

```
SeedRandom[1]
points = RandomReal[1, {10, 3}];
mesh = ConvexHullMesh[points]
```

[image]

Using [`LinearOptimization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearOptimization):

```
{A, b} = LinearOptimization[0, {}, x ∈ mesh, "LinearInequalityConstraints"];
```

Visualization check of the half-space representation:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
    ImplicitRegion[Thread[A.{x,y,z} + b > 0], {x, y, z}],
    MaxCellMeasure->"Length"->.005
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This should do.

```
(* faster ans listable version of Cross for 3-dim vectors *)
Block[{X,Y},
 cCross = With[{code = Cross[
      Table[Compile`GetElement[X, i], {i, 1, 3}], 
      Table[Compile`GetElement[Y, i], {i, 1, 3}]
      ]
     },
   Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}, {Y, _Real, 1}},
    code,
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ]
  ];

{p1, p2, p3} = Transpose[Partition[
    MeshCoordinates[M][[Flatten[MeshCells[M, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]]]], 
    3]];
A = cCross[p2 - p1, p3 - p1];
A /= Sqrt[(A^2).ConstantArray[1., 3]];
b = NDSolve`FEM`MapThreadDot[p1, A];
```

Here, `A` is the list of face normals and thus can be computed by the cross product of two of each face's edge vectors. `b` can be evaluated by innerproduct of *any* point on the face with the face normal.

We exploit here that the mesh returned by `ConvexHullMesh` is a triangle mesh.